# JQuery Scrollbar on datagrid footer

Tags: datagrid, footer, jquery-easyui

I try to create datagrid with footer that's will show as many unique data rows in that field. The problem is the footer will taking more space when more unique data is inserted, what am I try to do is to set the footer with scroll bar and I am stack on it.

It's possible to set footer datagrid with it'sown scrollbar? Can anyone tell me how to do it